# Can I host a Terraria server on my iPad then play it on a PC?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

Is it possible to host a Terraria server on a iPad 7 and play the server on a PC? Me and my brother really wants me to play on the iPad and he plays on the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Cross platform support is not currently available. I also cannot see any official source to suggest it is planned either.

If you search for "Terraria cross platform multiplayer" you should find lots of info with people speculating the reasons *why* it isn't supported. For example, different platforms aren't even on the same game version.